# Unable to set cookie in next.js API route from a CURL command

Tags: reactjs, cookies, next.js

TLDR: I'm trying to set a cookie in a `Next.js` API route by calling a CURL command. The cookie is not being set in my browser as expected.

Here is the API Route code:

```
import { setCookie } from 'cookies-next'

export default function handler(req, res) {
    setCookie('test', 'test12345', {
        req,
        res,
        maxAge: 34000,
        path: '/',
        domain: '/',
        sameSite: 'none', // Set to 'none' for third-party cookies
        secure: true // Required for 'none'
    })

    console.log('after cookie set')

    res.status(200).send(`Hello, test!`)
}
```

Details:

To Reproduce my issue:

- clone this repo to your machine: https://github.com/Jared-Dahlke/nextjs-cookie-problem
- run `npm i`
- run `npm run dev`
- open your browser to localhost:3000
- run `curl "http://localhost:3000/api/hello"`

**- actual result: observe that the cookie is not set in your browser**

**- expected result: cookie is set in your browser**

Note: i've tried all possible cookies libraries that i know of including:

- `serialize` from `cookie` library
- `next-cookies` library
- `nookies` library

I've also tried all different cookie settings I could think of, such as:

- `sameSite: 'none'`
- `sameSite: 'lax'`
- `secure: true`
- `httpOnly: true`
  etc.

I could be missing something. I also tried chatGPT and googled around . Been stuck on this for a while. Hopefully it's something glaringly obvious I am doing wrong or some misunderstanding of how this works.